# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)dx$ and $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sin(bx)dx$ for $a>0$ using complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, problem-solving, contour-integration

I am a Mathematics student.Currently I am doing exercises of complex analysis from Stein Shakarchi's book.In the second chapter,there is a problem which is as follows:

> Evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)dx$ and $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sin(bx)dx$ for $a>0$ by integrating $e^{-Az}$ ,$A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ over an appropriate sector with angle $\omega$ given by $\cos(\omega)=a/A$.

I am unable to solve this problem.It is clear that I have to apply Cauchy's theorem to the prescribed contour.Can someone provide some clue so that I can do this problem,for example the first few steps or a sketch of all steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrals are the real and imaginary parts of $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{(-a+ib) x} \text dx$. Let $\theta\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ such that $a-ib = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} e^{i\theta}$.

Now, let $R>0$ and consider a contour $\Gamma$, consisting of the line segment $\Gamma_1$ joining $0$ and $R \in (0,+\infty)$, the line segment $\Gamma_2$ joining $0$ to $Re^{-i\theta}$ and the portion of a circle $\Gamma_3$ centered at zero and joining $R$ and $Re^{-i\theta}$.

Then, Cauchy's theorem implies that :
$$\int_{\Gamma} e^{(-a+ib)z}\text dz = \int_{\Gamma_1} e^{(-a+ib)z}\text dz+\int_{\Gamma_2} e^{(-a+ib)z}\text dz+\int_{\Gamma_3} e^{(-a+ib)z}\text dz= 0$$

The integral over $\Gamma_1$ gives $\int_0^R e^{(-a+ib)x}\text dx$, the integral over $\Gamma_2$ gives $-\int_0^R e^{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}x}e^{-i\theta}\text dx$ and the integral over $\Gamma_3$ is bounded by $Re^{-\cos(\theta) R}$. Because this last piece goes to zero, we can take the limit $R\to +\infty$ to get :
$$\int_0^{+\infty}e^{(-a+ib)x}\text dx = e^{-i\theta}\int_0^{+\infty} e^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}x}\text dx = \frac{e^{-i\theta}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \frac{1}{a-ib} \tag{1}$$

Taking the real and imaginary part, we get :
\begin{align}
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\cos(bx)\text dx &= \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} \\
\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-ax}\sin(bx) \text dx &= \frac{b}{a^2+b^2}
\end{align}

**NB** Note that here the contour integral is overkill since we can get $(1)$ by computing the anti-derivative explicitely.

Comment: No,I am not allowed to integrate $e^{(-a+ib)z}$ ,I am allowed to integrate only $e^{-Az}$.

Comment: I was pointing out that this is only a restriction from the exercise, and that this integral can actually be readily computed.

Comment: Yeah, but @KishalaySarkar's point is that the above doesn't "integrate $$e^{-Az} = e^{-z\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$ over a sector" as suggested by Stein-Shakarchi; it integrates $$e^{(-a + ib)z}$$ over the sector. I'm puzzled by this exercise too.